# Retrieving paths of FileSystemInfo instances

Tags: c++, filesystems, path

How does one retrieve ( or resolve, for that matter ) the absolute and relative ( FullPath and OriginalPath fields ) paths of FileSystemInfo/DirectoyInfo/FileInfo instances ? I'm trying to get the paths of the files/directories returned by a FileSystemInfos call on a DirectoryInfo class object.

Comment: I must be missing something? FullPath and OriginalPath properties are available on FileSystemInfo objects returned from DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the FullName property gets you the full path of the directory or file.

Comment: Figured that out sometime after I posted.

@Simon Fox, the FullPath and OriginalPath fields are protected - I can't seem to use them.